# Survey App in Android with Branching

Tags: android, android-viewpager, branch, survey

I would like to implement a Survey in Android with Branching (Skip Logic). My first solution is to use ViewPager with Tab. However, I got a problem with branching. For example, the normal flow is that user answers questions from 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6. However, if in question 1, user choose answer A among 4 answers A, B, C and D then the flow will skip question 4 and 5. So the new flow will be 1, 2, 3, and 6. When I implement ViewPager, I use 6 tabs in actionBar. I want to change these tabs according to user's answer after each question. Can I still use ViewPager or there is another solution?
Note that: I would also like to keep the answers after each question so that user can review again before they submit.

Comment: I would probably not use viewPager for that as the user will likely assume they can swipe to switch tabs which I don't think you want.

Comment: Thank you very much @IanSellar. Could you please suggest me another alternative? I may try with Activities but after move to next Activity then have to finish the current Activity. I would like to keep the current activity so that user can review answers again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement this using activities for each question but I think the best way would be to use [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) for each survey question. You could jump to a certain question fragment by storing them in an ordered array in the activity and switching to the one you want.

Comment: Thank much @IanSellar. I would like to know if there is an example for using fragments that can import directly into Eclipse. I am new to this programming.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote/accept answer if you like it :) https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html